# removing css class with jquery when window reaches certain width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add and remove some classes to some  elements i have. I am using bootstrap, i currently have the site www.iampaulb.com which looks rather good (for a first attempt) on mobile like my iPhone but on a desktop not so much.

this is the div in question:

```
<div id="demo1" class="collapse in">
    <legend class="main-legend">Hello! I am Paul...</legend>
```

the .collapse in class closes the div on load (so you need to press the button to open) I would like to remove that class and use the class .collapse which will leave the content open on load. I have looked through here and tried various things. Such as

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
  windowsize = $(window).width();
  if (windowsize > 800) {
    //if window width is greater than 800px make tab visable
      $('#demo').addClass('collapse');
  }
})
```

But it doesnt seem to work. :(

Any suggestions? FYI i am a jQuery Noob
;

#

Ok i have used one of the suggestions here and it has worked brilliantly.
But only when the browser is being resized manually...this is what i have

```
$(window).on("resize.showContent", function() {
    windowsize = $(window).width();
    if(windowsize > 800) {
        $(".collapse:first").addClass("in").removeAttr("style");
    }
}).trigger("resize.showContent")

$(window).on("resize.showContent", function() {
    windowsize = $(window).width();
    if(windowsize < 800) {
        $(".collapse:first").removeClass("in").removeAttr("style");
    }
}).trigger("resize.showContent") 

// change of button for top element

$(window).on("resize.showContent", function() {
    windowsize = $(window).width();
    if(windowsize > 800) {
        $("#button1").removeClass("large btn-block").addClass("btn-link").removeAttr("style");
    }
}).trigger("resize.showContent")

$(window).on("resize.showContent", function() {
    windowsize = $(window).width();
    if(windowsize < 800) {
        $("#button1").removeClass("btn-link").addClass("-large btn-block").removeAttr("style");
    }
}).trigger("resize.showContent")
```

This enables the section to expand and removes the button class so it shows a s link.
But what would i amened to make it defaul when say on an iphone or desktop. Would it be a case of just removing the `resize.` ? hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
    var resizing = false;

    function doResize() {
        var w=$(window).innerWidth();
        //(UPDATE)do add remove of CSS-classes, according to w / needs
        if (w > 800) {
            $('#demo1').addClass('collapse'); //you have demo1 as id in the code
        } else {
            $('#demo1').removeClass('collapse');
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        //use timeouts not to trigger event constantly
        if (resizing!==false) {
            clearTimeout(resizing);
        } 
        resizing=setTimeout(doResize, 200);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to toggle the css class you could just use the jquery [toggeClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

and when you load the page you could just trigger the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    $('#demo').toggleClass('collapse', (windowsize > 800));
}).trigger("resize");
```

after looking at your page... isnt it the class "on" you want to toggle, if window size is less then 800 then add the "in" class to the collapse elements?

### edit3

```
var displayFirstBlock = function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width(),
        isDesktop = windowsize > 800;
    $(".collapse:first").toggleClass("in", isDesktop).removeAttr("style");
    $("#button1").toggleClass("large btn-block", !isDesktop).toggleClass("btn-link", isDesktop);
}

$(window).on("resize.showContent", displayFirstBlock);
displayFirstBlock();
```

binds an event on the resize and should be called immediately.

Comment: Brilliant this works to a certain extent...how would i replace collapse with collapse in because with collapse it leaves the section open which is brilliant...but it overlays all the others which isnt so great...is this because its removed the class completely? when screen is > 800

Comment: look at the new response, it will add the class "in" and remove the attribute style if the windowsize is greater then 800... you may not want to bind this on the resize event, you may want to load it only once per page load?

Comment: if you were female (not sure if you are) i would bloody kiss you!!!! Just what i wanted...thank you SO MUCH --- So if i wanted to do that with another button would i just have to replace .collapse:first with .collapse:second and so on?

Comment: no, :first and :last is a css selector, what you have to do is get `$(".collapse:eq(1)")` then to get the second `.collapse` read more on `:eq`: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ I edited my first response to maybe fit your new question better.

Comment: This is working great so thank you. But its not working how id like with window sizes...if the browser opens say on an iphone it the top button is expanded untill its moved slightly...it doesnt seem to detech if is a smaller or large res untill its been manually resized by user, even if it s a pixel difference :/

Comment: lets try to call it without an event (look at the last method block on my first post).

Comment: so this one? $(window).resize(function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    $('#demo').toggleClass('collapse', (windowsize > 800));
}).trigger("resize");